# What are the names and grades of Zoro's swords?

Tags: one-piece

Zoro always (almost always) carries 3 swords with him. So the question is, what are the names and the grades of those 3 swords he is currently carrying?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following are the names and grades of the 3 swords currently (as of 16-April-2020) carried by Zoro.

- [Wado Ichimonji](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Wado_Ichimonji)

  > The Wado Ichimonji is a sword of great personal importance to Roronoa Zoro, and it was once Kuina's and her family's sword. It is also one of the [**21 O Wazamono grade**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Meito#21_O_Wazamono_Grade_Swords) swords.
- [Sandai Kitetsu](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sandai_Kitetsu)

  > The Sandai Kitetsu is one of the [**Wazamono grade**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Meito#Wazamono_Grade_Swords) swords, a "Sharp Sword". Like all of its predecessor Kitetsu swords, this one is said to be cursed.
- [Enma](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Enma) (exchanged with the Shusui)

  > Enma is one of the [**21 O Wazamono grade**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Meito#21_O_Wazamono_Grade_Swords) swords. It was once wielded by Kozuki Oden alongside his other sword, Ame no Habakiri, and is one of the two only weapons known to have ever injured Kaido.
  >   After Oden's death, Enma was inherited by his daughter, Kozuki Hiyori. Hiyori would later gift the sword to Roronoa Zoro in exchange for the latter allowing Shusui, a national treasure, to remain in Wano.

**Past Swords:**

- [Yubashiri](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yubashiri) (now destroyed and replaced by Shusui)

  > Yubashiri was one of the fifty [**Ryo Wazamono grade**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Meito#50_Ryo_Wazamono_Grade_Swords) sword. Roronoa Zoro obtained this sword for free from a sword shop owner.
- [Shusui](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Shusui) (exchanged for Enma)

  > Shusui is one of the [**21 O Wazamono grade**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Meito#21_O_Wazamono_Grade_Swords) swords and was once wielded by the legendary samurai Ryuma. It is considered the national treasure of the Wano Country. After his death, the katana was buried with Ryuma, until his grave was robbed by Moriah's crew. Ryuma appeared as a zombie on Thriller Bark, who had been given Brook's shadow. After his defeat, Ryuma bequeathed the sword to Roronoa Zoro and said he was satisfied with Zoro as the sword's master.

Answer (score 1):

Enma is zoro's new sword, he got it at wano. Enma was Komurasaki's sword whom also gave the sword to Zoro for his Shisui.Since Shisui is Wano's legendary sword. Enma was one of Oden's sword; the only man who dealt damage to Kaido. (Which is why Kaido has that huge X on his chest, kinda like Luffy.)